# Suddenly a lot of sharepoint sites get the error "Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem..."

Tags: error, hotfix

There are three weeks that I am receiving some reports about the error:
In sites that were working fine.

The error is:

> Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open
>   this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML
>   editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists,
>   contact your Web server administrator.
>
> Correlation ID:XXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX

It happens in views of lists.

Do you know if there are something happening? Like a update that messed everything? And if there are some fix?

Comment: I think, you need to provide SharePoint Log information according to Correlation ID.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was a issua of a Microsoft Update in my server.

I found some forums relating the same problem.

Was installed in my Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 the KB2844286 Security Update.

To fix it you can unistall KB2844286 or you can install an update in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872441

More details see 
http://techchucker.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/issue-kb2844286-security-update-on-sharepoint-2010/

and

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/cc9a557b-93cd-40d5-965c-e0a2f107624d/unable-to-display-this-web-part-error-message-after-patch-kb2844286

Comment: Dude, why didn't I think of that? I fixed the same problem last week!

Comment: @longneck I did the same, last week.

Comment: Notice that microsoft have updated it's blog today. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872441 , with a real fix.

Comment: It seems that this issue has reappeared with KB4016446 - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4016446/forms-in-dynamics-crm-2011-are-not-displayed-correctly-after-kb-401307

Answer (score 0):

If there are many columns in the view, you can get this error. Maybe you can check the columns and try to remove columns from the view one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Go to a page that gives this error and add `?contents=1` to the end of the URL. Note what webparts are listed. Repeat this for a couple of pages that return an error and see what webparts are common. You might need to reinstall that webpart or simply remove it from the page.

Also check if lists behind any Data View Web Parts have permissions that are too strict. If a user doesn't have access to a list but opens a page with a Data View Web Part on it that draws from that list you can get that error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the resources the webpart is using has the right permissions.

> For Eg. The webpart may be accessing data from site assets/style
>   library etc. So check the permissions of user on the corresponding
>   library from webpart.

If the user doesn't have the necessary permission then you won't be able to see the webpart n SP will give you error

> "Unable to display this Web Part"

It Worked for me. Check!