# "Unable to display this Web Part" error in browser

Tags: error, custom-form

I have a custom list form created in Designer. It displays in Designer but in the browser I get the following error

```
Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Windows SharePoint Services-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.
```

How can I work out where in the page the problem is?

Comment: Check ULS logs if you find any specific errors related to your form.  You must have some broken elements in your form.  Also check for duplicate web parts in SharePoint designer.

Answer (score 1):

When I have experienced this error, it's usually do to invalid XSLT in the web part. Something as simple as leaving off a quote or a backslash will result in this error when loading your page. Sometimes I even have to blow away the web part and start over because I can't find anything wrong after staring at the code. But when I do find the problem, it's usually something super simple that I missed.

If this is 2007 or 2010, looking at the page in SharePoint Designer's design view should give you a better clue as to what's broken. Invalid XSLT will usually show an error on the page there like "Error: invalid token -->@@<--." or something like that.

Comment: You can use for highlighted text in yellow color also. Its definitely bad XSLT which is making problem

Answer (score 0):

More details on what the web part does would be helpful. But some steps you can use to trouble shoot.

- append ?contents=1 to the URL after .aspx which will allow you to
  remove the Web Part. Try re- adding through the browser instead.
- Enable verbose ULS logging through Central Admin
- Check Event Viewer

Answer (score 0):

make sure the resources the webpart is using has the right permissions. For Eg. The webpart may be accessing data from site assets/style library etc. So check the permissions of user on the corresponding library from webpart. If the user doesnt have the necessary permission then you wont be able to see the webpart n SP will give you error "Unable to display this Web Part"

It Worked for me. Check!

Comment: Please don't add the same answer here as you did on [this question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74794/suddenly-a-lot-of-sharepoint-sites-get-the-error-unable-to-display-this-web-par/191242#191242). Try to be more specific, or if the questions are equal - flag as duplicate answer. Thank you